# Menu Responsivo - Quando a página está no seu tamanho normal, a lista do menu não fica inline (deveria ficar um ao lado do outro)

Tags: menu, layout-responsivo

Vocês podem observar o código no codepen. Não consigo deixar, quando a página está em seu tamanho normal, o menu com as opções inline-block, mesmo que isso esteja no código. Ele continua se comportando apenas como um bloco, um em cima do outro. Deveria fazer isso apenas quando a página chega ao 700px, e a lista vai para baixo da página, deixando um link "menu" em cima.

https://codepen.io/ysalemos/pen/MWwzXxZ?editors=1100

Código do link

```css
html{
    background-color: #CACFD2;
}

body {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    background-color: #424949;
    padding: 30px;
}


p{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#CACFD2;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color:#EAEDED;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
}


.navegacao a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#EAEDED;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEDED;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.iniciador{
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEDED;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#EAEDED;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width:700px){
    .iniciador{
        display:none;
    }
    .navegacao{
        position:absolute;
        top:-30px;
    }
    .navegacao li{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Importância de Star Wars para o cinema </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans|Open+Sans:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#menu" class="iniciador" id="link-menu">Menu</a>
        
        <h1> Importância de Star Wars para o cinema </h1>
         <p> Inicialmente, o Episódio IV: Uma Nova Esperança seria o único filme sobre Star Wars feito por George Lucas. A produção conta a história da princesa Leia Organa, que é presa por fazer parte da resistência e também por roubar os planos do projeto secreto imperial, a Estrela da Morte. Mas antes que Darth Vader consiga pegar os planos, Leia os coloca no droide R2-D2 e, ao lado de C3-PO, ele vai atrás de Obi-Wan Kenobi. É nesse momento que conhecemos Luke Skywalker, um jovem que sempre quis sair de Tatooine e conhecer o universo, mas foi impedido pelos tios, que temiam que o garoto se tornasse como o seu pai, Anakin Skywalker. Mais tarde, em outros filmes da franquia, Luke é treinado pelo mestre Yoda e se torna um grande Jedi. </p>
    
         <p> Com um roteiro futurista, Star Wars caiu nas graças no público não somente pela história, mas por apresentar um universo surreal e transformá-lo em algo verossímil aos nossos olhos. Além disso, personagens humanos se misturam com outras criaturas de maneira convincente, como é o caso de Han Solo e o seu companheiro, Chewbacca. Há também a presença de muitos personagens com perfil carismático, como é o caso de Luke, o herói do filme, Leia, Han Solo, Chewbacca e também os droides. Até mesmo Darth Vader, um vilão icônico para o mundo do cinema, consegue transparecer certo carisma. Ele é um vilão que, na verdade, pode ser considerado nosso herói. </p>
        
         <p> Por esses e outros motivos, Star Wars se tornou um fenômeno e ajudou a fundar o cinema moderno, elevando o conceito de ‘blockbuster’, que começou com o filme Tubarão (1975), de Steven Spielberg. Sucesso de críticas, George Lucas lançou, no total, seis filmes, divididos em duas trilogias: a que conta a jornada de Luke Skywalker e a dedicada à história da transformação de Anakin Skywalker em Darth Vader. E como o universo de Star Wars é gigantesco e repleto de possibilidades, em 2015 estreou O Despertar da Força, o sétimo episódio de Star Wars, também aclamado pela crítica, alcançando 92% no Rotten Tomatoes (apenas 1% a menos que Uma Nova Esperança). </p>
        
         <p> Além de ter praticamente inaugurado a era dos ‘blockbusters’, Star Wars também foi um dos primeiros filmes a lançar produtos licenciados relacionados ao universo, como diversos livros e quadrinhos, artigos de colecionador, brinquedos, etc. E não só isso: a frase ‘que a Força esteja com você’ foi eleita a 8º frase mais memorável pelo AFI (American Film Institute) e Darth Vader o 3º maior vilão do cinema americano. FONTE: http://cinematecando.com.br/ </p>
        
        <div id="menu" class="navegacao">
         <ul>
             <li> <a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Vader</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Leia Organa</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Han Solo</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Luke Skywalker</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: olá, coloque o código aqui na sua pergunta, clique em editar e no icone `<>` pode adicionar o código completo, nem todos acessam os outros sites, além de ficar melhor para ver e entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc está usando `min-width` então é dentro desse `@media` que vc tem que mudar a classe de `display:block` para `display:inline-block`, ai ele vai ficar em linha.

Ali vc tb tem que ajustar o `top`, não deve ser `-30p`x, tem que ser `30px`, para afastar `30px` do top e não para ficar `30px` acima do topo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código da imagem acima

```css
html{
    background-color: #CACFD2;
}

body {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    background-color: #424949;
    padding: 30px;
}


p{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#CACFD2;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color:#EAEDED;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
}


.navegacao a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#EAEDED;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEDED;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.iniciador{
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEDED;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#EAEDED;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width:700px){
    .iniciador{
        display:none;
    }
    .navegacao{
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
    }
    .navegacao li{
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
    <a href="#menu" class="iniciador" id="link-menu">Menu</a>
    
    <h1> Importância de Star Wars para o cinema </h1>
     <p> Inicialmente, o Episódio IV: Uma Nova Esperança seria o único filme sobre Star Wars feito por George Lucas. A produção conta a história da princesa Leia Organa, que é presa por fazer parte da resistência e também por roubar os planos do projeto secreto imperial, a Estrela da Morte. Mas antes que Darth Vader consiga pegar os planos, Leia os coloca no droide R2-D2 e, ao lado de C3-PO, ele vai atrás de Obi-Wan Kenobi. É nesse momento que conhecemos Luke Skywalker, um jovem que sempre quis sair de Tatooine e conhecer o universo, mas foi impedido pelos tios, que temiam que o garoto se tornasse como o seu pai, Anakin Skywalker. Mais tarde, em outros filmes da franquia, Luke é treinado pelo mestre Yoda e se torna um grande Jedi. </p>

     <p> Com um roteiro futurista, Star Wars caiu nas graças no público não somente pela história, mas por apresentar um universo surreal e transformá-lo em algo verossímil aos nossos olhos. Além disso, personagens humanos se misturam com outras criaturas de maneira convincente, como é o caso de Han Solo e o seu companheiro, Chewbacca. Há também a presença de muitos personagens com perfil carismático, como é o caso de Luke, o herói do filme, Leia, Han Solo, Chewbacca e também os droides. Até mesmo Darth Vader, um vilão icônico para o mundo do cinema, consegue transparecer certo carisma. Ele é um vilão que, na verdade, pode ser considerado nosso herói. </p>
    
     <p> Por esses e outros motivos, Star Wars se tornou um fenômeno e ajudou a fundar o cinema moderno, elevando o conceito de ‘blockbuster’, que começou com o filme Tubarão (1975), de Steven Spielberg. Sucesso de críticas, George Lucas lançou, no total, seis filmes, divididos em duas trilogias: a que conta a jornada de Luke Skywalker e a dedicada à história da transformação de Anakin Skywalker em Darth Vader. E como o universo de Star Wars é gigantesco e repleto de possibilidades, em 2015 estreou O Despertar da Força, o sétimo episódio de Star Wars, também aclamado pela crítica, alcançando 92% no Rotten Tomatoes (apenas 1% a menos que Uma Nova Esperança). </p>
    
     <p> Além de ter praticamente inaugurado a era dos ‘blockbusters’, Star Wars também foi um dos primeiros filmes a lançar produtos licenciados relacionados ao universo, como diversos livros e quadrinhos, artigos de colecionador, brinquedos, etc. E não só isso: a frase ‘que a Força esteja com você’ foi eleita a 8º frase mais memorável pelo AFI (American Film Institute) e Darth Vader o 3º maior vilão do cinema americano. FONTE: http://cinematecando.com.br/ </p>
    
    <div id="menu" class="navegacao">
     <ul>
         <li> <a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Vader</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Leia Organa</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Han Solo</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Luke Skywalker</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Obrigada... Conseguiu esclarecer. Esse é o meu primeiro projeto responsivo e ainda estou com dificuldades em algumas coisas pequenas. Foi de muita ajuda.

Comment: @MaysaSantiago fico feliz em ter ajudado, fique firme nos estudos, boa sorte!